# Attaching a jQuery .js file to an html document

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would need help on attaching my .js document to my html document so that jQuery works on it, at the moment only normal JS is working.

This is the html document header (called "3i.html"):

```
<!PROCTYPE <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>3i.com</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="3i.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="3i.js"></script>
</head>
```

The javascript file is called "3i.js".
Javascript commands like "alert" or "prompt" work fine, I just can't find a way to make jQuery code work.

Help is very much appreciated

Comment: You need to refer the jQuery library like `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` and don't forget [document-ready handler](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

Comment: jQuery is a library and not part of standard js, as of that you need load jQuery the same way you load `3i.js`: [learn.jquery.com: How jQuery Works](https://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/). If you want to use it  in `i3.js` then you need load jQuery before that script.

Answer (score 0):

Include the jQuery library and your .js file just before closing the body.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>3i.com</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="3i.css">
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="3i.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```